# Windows 7 Auto logon

Tags: windows-7, passwords, login, automatic-logon

I'm using Windows 7 professional Service Pack 1 on my desktop computer.
Every single time I turn on or wake up my computer, I must enter my password which is quite annoying. 
I'm the only user of this computer and of course have administrator privileges.

I did everything in any online help resources that I could find out there, but none of them worked.

```
1) Win + run
2) control userpasswords2
3) Un-check "Users must enter a username and password to use this computer"
```

But it does not work.

What should I do ??

Comment: it should be `control userpasswords2` instead of `control userpassword2`

Answer (score 8):

Just download [Autologon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx) from Microsoft Sysinternals.

> Autologon enables you to easily configure Windows’ built-in autologon mechanism. Instead of waiting for a user to enter their name and password, Windows uses the credentials you enter with Autologon, which are encrypted in the Registry, to log on the specified user automatically.
>
> Autologon is easy enough to use. Just run autologon.exe, fill in the dialog, and hit Enable. To turn off auto-logon, hit Disable. Also, if the shift key is held down before the system performs an autologon, the autologon will be disabled for that logon. You can also pass the username, domain and password as command-line arguments: autologon user domain password

If you're not in a domain, you can specify the computer name instead. You shouldn't need to change the domain text box when you use the GUI version, just type the user name and password. For the command line version it would be something like this:

```
autologon userName computerName passWord
```

By using `autologon`, you don't lose the password on your account and don't get prompted to click on your username either, you'll just login automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this via the registry:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`

`AutoAdminLogon = 1`

`DefaultUserName = >username<`

`DefaultPassword = >password<`

`DefaultDomain = >machine name or domain name<`

Optional: You can add in...

`AltDefaultUsername = >username<`
...

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember exactly how I did it on a newly installed computer but you could try removing the password from your account.

Did you get the popup to verify what account to auto login?

Answer (score 1):

Go to User Account Controls

- Control Panel
- User accounts
- Click 'Remove Password'
- Enter your password in the 'Current Password' field
- then click 'Remove Password'

No more password required at start up or from a sleep state.

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd and enter `netplwiz`, then proceed to uncheck the box for `Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer`.
I tried and this solved for both Windows 7 and 10.