# Windows 7 Automatic Log-on with a Default User Account?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have two User Accounts for my Windows 7 with no password requirement. I frequently use one of those accounts; so I would like Windows to log-on automatically with that account without the need for user input.

P.S. I don't prefer installing/using a third-party software for that purpose; especially those that place at low levels before Windows log-on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Windows 7 allow auto-login with a stored password, like TweakUI did?](http://superuser.com/questions/243681/does-windows-7-allow-auto-login-with-a-stored-password-like-tweakui-did) and [Windows 7 Auto logon](http://superuser.com/questions/460475/windows-7-auto-logon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In the Start menu search box enter `netplwiz` to open the Advanced User Accounts panel.
- Go to the Users tab and uncheck "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer".
- Click apply and when the dialog appears select the user you want to logon automatically and enter the password (if any).
- Click OK. Done.