# Windows 10 tries to login with the local user instead of Microsoft account

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-outlook, user-accounts, login

Background for the story:
I had created a local Windows user on my laptop, lets say `dummyuser`. Later on I connected that local user with the Microsoft account `dummyuser@outlook.com`.

I want to login to Windows directly without specifying any password. But because it is a microsoft account, I need to have the password set. I overcame this issue by removing "users must enter password to use this computer".

[image]

Which kind of works, but the issues is that Windows tries to login with the local user `dummyuser`, not `dummyuser@outlook.com` and thus complains about that the password is wrong.

How can I make Windows to start using the microsoft account to login? Also checking the User Profiles shows only one User profile (Control Panel\User Accounts\User Accounts)

Comment: Based on the screenshot provided you only have a single account.  This means by default Windows should automatically log into the account.  Verify that `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` DefaultUserName is set to the correct username.

Comment: The process to set a default account that is automatically logged in has not changed.  [Windows 10: Sign in User Account Automatically at Windows 10 Startup](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3539-sign-user-account-automatically-windows-10-startup.html) outside of the fact that a connect account will always have a password.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Ramhound. I got the issue resolved with enabling/disabling the checkbox again and when was prompted with the username and password I specified `dummyuser@outlook.com as the user to use. So this is kind of related with the [Windows 7 Automatic Log-on with a Default User Account?](https://superuser.com/questions/733282/windows-7-automatic-log-on-with-a-default-user-account), but I still had only one account in my case. Toggling back and forth seems to be the fix for this bug/issue.