# Remove all login security on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, security, login

I am incredibly annoyed by Windows 10 forcing me to setup a pin, or otherwise asking for my Microsoft password.

I would like to disable all sort of login security, I want my computer to start and open. I have no concerns for security, the computer is in my home, and have nothing but games on it.

I already did manipulation to remove pin, it worked well until the computer crashed once, and then it asked me to create a pin again, it’s just insane!

Please someone tell me it’s possible to remove all those securities, I beg you.

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1212440/windows-10-tries-to-login-with-the-local-user-instead-of-microsoft-account)

Comment: You may need to use a *local* account, i.e. not at Microsoft. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/switch-your-windows-10-device-to-a-local-account-eb7e78a9-88ee-9bc3-8f06-831b56e339fd

Comment: Thanks @DrMoishePippik that was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

> `netplwiz`

[image]

And then you enter more characters into the answer, because a picture may be worth one thousand words, but the naïve code thinks that 8 characters isn't enough to answer a question.

Comment: That's what I did, and alas, after a crash, it asked me to create a pin again...

Comment: This solution may no longer work in 2022. It seems it doesn't for me and many others online, anyway. By the way, 8 characters isn't enough for this answer: it seems to me that many people won't understand what `netplwiz` means, that it's a command that should be entered into windows launcher, they might not know how to start windows launcher (windows key + r), etc.

Comment: @CalebJay Fortunately you just told them!

Answer (score -2):

Under Settings, you could go to Accounts > Sign-in options. Then, go to Require sign-in and choose Never. You'll still have to enter your pin if you reboot the computer, but this will reduce the number of times you need to do that.

Edit: turns out I was wrong! See the other answers.

Comment: You can easily setup Windows 10 to automatically without any user interaction to log into the account of your choice even if it’s connected to a Microsoft Account.